# How do I retrieve developer's repository information from github using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, github-api

This follows from a series of tutorials which I am currently doing to learn nodejs. I want to access the repository information of users on developer.github.com. When I try to use the following piece of code it shows an error:

json.forEach(function(repo){
             ^
TypeError: Object # has no method 'forEach'

```
var https=require("https");

var username= "OllieParsley";

var options={
    host: "api.github.com",
    path: "/users/" +username+ "/repos",
    method: "GET",
    /*customHeaders: { "User-Agent": "app" }*/
};

var request= https.request(options, function(response){
    var body='';
    response.on("data", function(chunk){
        body+=chunk.toString("utf8");
    });
    response.on("end", function(){
        var repos=[];       
        var json=JSON.parse(body);
        json.forEach(function(repo){
            repos.push({
                name:repo.name,
                description:repo.descripton         
            });

        });     
        console.log("Repos: ", repos);  
    });
});
request.end();
```

Any pointers why does the error say object has no method 'forEach'?

Comment: If `json` is an object and not an array, then it does not have a method `forEach`. What is exactly depends on what the API returns. Also make sure `body` is actually contains valid JSON. Do `console.log(body)` and `console.log(json)` and see what their values are.

Comment: ya the api is configured differently now. Thanks!

Comment: @AnishShah how did you fix this also how did you set that path . I was having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `Object.keys(json).forEach(...)` instead. Obviously do `var repo = json[key];` inside the `forEach` block.

Comment: what is the purpose of doing var repo=json[key]; inside the forEach block when the argument I am passing is repo?

Comment: cause you're iterating the keys in my solution